# Text formatting in for loop

Tags: c, printf

I have a very basic idea that I want to implement but somehow my logic for this isn't the best one since the code is not working as I want it to.

I want to have numbers written on screen/in text file in such way that after 20 iterrations there's new line which separates them.

Please take a look.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * File = fopen("NUMBERS.txt", "w");
    int *a;

    int n;
    int i;
    int j;
    int r;

    printf("How many numbers do you wish to enter?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    a = malloc(n*sizeof(int*));

    time_t t;

    srand((unsigned)time(&t));

    fprintf(File, "%d\n", n);

    for(i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
    {
        r = rand() % 100;
        a[i]= r;
        printf("%d ", r);

        fprintf(File, "%d ", r);

        if(a[i] % 20 == 0)
        {
            printf("\n");
            fprintf(File, "\n");
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Lets say that the user enters (21 or any higher number) the output should be:

`21
67 24 8 10 27 83 7 89 99 40 69 5 69 12 66 92 99 16 37 22 
42`

Comment: Note: `a = malloc(n*sizeof(int));` or even better : `a = malloc(n*sizeof *a);`

Comment: @wildplasser - You're right, but I doubt brajevicm notices the issue, since it's likely that `int` uses less bytes then `int *` (or at most, the same number of bytes) :-p ... but brajevicm, if you're reading this, fix the `malloc`, it's painful to look at.

Comment: I changed it as soon as I saw it. It was probably just a typo.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a line break after 20 iterations you need to check the `i` variable used in the iteration instead of the value of the i'th item in the array, so replace

`if(a[i] % 20 == 0)` with `if(i % 20 == 0)`

Also, the memory allocation is incorrect as pointed out in another answer (and comment).